# iOS 8 showFromToolbar effect with UIActionController

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, uiactionsheet, uialertcontroller

`UIActionController` replaced `UIActionSheet` in iOS 8. Is there any way to recreate the [showFromToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIActionSheet/showFromToolbar:) behavior of `UIActionSheet` in `UIActionController`? [This is the effect I am seeking](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2011/08/26/using-uiactionsheet-for-external-actions.html). Please note though that I am trying to draw a UIActionController coming out of an external action bar button on an iPhone, so I couldn't do this using generic UIActionSheet example too I suppose.

I created a `UIBarButtonItem` and, in its `IBAction` I am creating a `UIActionController`. I tried the following:

```
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "XYZ", message: "XYZ", preferredStyle: .Alert
    // Then created a bunch of UIAlertAction items and added them to alert
    var popover = alert.popoverPresentationController
    if popover != nil {
        var s = sender as UIBarButtonItem
        popover?.sourceView = s.customView
        popover?.sourceRect = s.customView!.bounds
        popover?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    } else {
        println("POPOVER is nil")
    }

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, this doesn't work with either iPhone or iPad simulators - the alert is showing in middle of screen and the above code always prints "POPOVER is nil". Even if it would have worked in iPad it wouldn't have solved my original problem. Your advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found this wonderful [tutorial](http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html) that explains how to do it.